# Dealing with a large c++ library in a Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a Rails project that is going to be using OpenCV, and it depends on a certain version of it (2.4.6.1).

I'm looking for deployment advice.  The Ubuntu opencv package is an earlier version and therefore not suitable.

I can see a number of possibilities, but I'm trying to think of what will work best.

- Just write it up in a README and expect people to follow it: download this, apt-get that, etc...
- Add opencv, tagged at the version we need, as a git subtree, and include a Rake task to build it.
- Write a script to download and compile the needed code.
- Something else ?

None of them seem all that great, to tell the truth.

Answer (score 1):

Can your application be made to work with OpenCV 2.4.2? That is [available in Ubuntu 13.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/raring/opencv), and you could request it be [backported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports) to 12.04. If not, you could update the source package to 2.4.6.1 (which would require learning about [debian packaging](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging) but might not be too difficult since you would be modifying an existing package instead of starting from scratch), upload it to a [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA), and instruct your users on Ubuntu to install OpenCV from there. You could also package your rails application and put it in the PPA, which would make overall installation even easier.

Comment: I remember a bit about Debian packaging, having been a Debian maintainer for a number of years, but 1) it's been a while, and 2) that package is something of a beast - it takes a long time to compile, so each time you need to restart the package generation process it takes a long time to finish.

The idea that we're currently working with is to statically compile the binary that uses OpenCV and distribute it with the rails app.  Since there's only the one app, we don't lose too many resources because of the static compile.